# redirect from http to https in Jetty

Tags: jetty

I want make permanent redirect from http:// myurl to https:// myurl, but in Jetty I find only MovedContextHandler, with it I can redirect only context path, for examnple from myurl/bla to myurl/bla/bla

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.MovedContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/bla</Set>
  <Set name="newContextURL">/bla/bla</Set>
  <Set name="permanent">true</Set>
  <Set name="discardPathInfo">false</Set>
  <Set name="discardQuery">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

but how can I work with prefix of url?

Comment: Duplicate [of this](http://serverfault.com/questions/367660/how-to-have-jetty-redirect-http-to-https)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best handled in your `/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```xml
<web-app>
  ...
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Everything in the webapp</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: @joakim-erdfelt Is the use of a SecureRequestCustomizer recommended when Jetty sees a 403 !SECURE error? See http://serverfault.com/a/575126 I currently have only static content.

Comment: @gouessej SecureRequestCustomizer is needed to trigger the "is secure" check on Jetty 9+ if you intend to redirect from a Jetty terminated SSL/TLS (https) to (http).  But more importantly is the requirement for a properly configured HttpConfiguration (as the redirect uses that information to perform the redirect) on your SSL/TLS (https) ServerConnectors

Comment: How to do it programmatically for a specific context handler?