# Jetty: Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for static content

Tags: java, xml, jetty, jetty-9

I have set up Jetty 9.3 with two XML context configurations. One for [static content](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/static-content-deployment.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/static</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="resourceBase">/home/user/static</Set>
      <Set name="directoriesListed">true</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

and one for a web application (WAR file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/webapp</Set>
  <Set name="war">/home/user/webapp.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

I then used [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/575126) to set up Jetty to forward HTTP requests to HTTPS. More specifically, I added the following to `jetty/etc/webdefault.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Everything</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
   <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

and added the following to my `HttpConfiguration` in `jetty/etc/jetty.xml`:

```
<Call name="addCustomizer">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer" />
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

This works perfectly for my web application (i.e. accessing the server through HTTP at '/webapp' will redirect to HTTPS), but doesn't seem to affect the static content served under '/static'. I assume this is because the setting added to `webdefault.xml` only applies to web applications since they have an applicable `web.xml` file.

How can I set up HTTP requests to redirect to HTTPS for all my pages served as static content?

Comment: What about `RewriteHandler` ? Maybe it will help you to solve your problem. Just serve static content by this handler.

Comment: You can use `nginx` for this, along with the `http` to `https` redirect you will get other advantages like static page cache.

Comment: Have you tried to use the default servlet + ServletContextHandler for your static content instead of ResourceHandler (which is very limited)? Maybe it would help. @srini In my humble opinion, using another HTTPD server (Apache, Nginx, ...) just for the redirections is a bit too much especially when your server has very limited resources. I use a small board with only one GB of RAM, I wouldn't follow your suggestion.

Comment: Related browser-side solution: [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). It will tell browsers to _always_ access resources on your domain through `HTTPS`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could tell (e.g., based on [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611815/redirect-from-http-to-https-in-jetty) and [this SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/367660/how-to-have-jetty-redirect-http-to-https/575126#575126) and the [Jetty Docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL#Redirecting_http_requests_to_https)) it's not configurable for static content, only for webapps.

What you *could* do (that does not mean that you *should* do it this way) is that you create a custom [`@PreMatching`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9767) filter if you are using JAX-RS or a custom [`MessageHandler`](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/api/handler/MessageHandler.html) if you are using JAX-WS which does the redirection programatically (e.g., through returning an HTTP 301).